# How can I compare two maps of different size

Tags: java, java-8

I have two maps with different size. For example

```
Map<String, Double> qm3 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Double> m = new HashMap<>();
```

qm3 has the following map `{d=0.2, e=0.3}`

m has the following map `{e=0.3, c=0.4, d=0.5}`

Now, I want to compare the keys of these two maps. If the first key of "qm3" matches with any of the keys of "m" then I want to store the values of qm3 in a list **qvec** and the values of m in another list **dvec**. and so on

I want to match each key of qm3 ( d, e) to each key of m (e, c ,d ).
For example ,d will be compared with e, c, d.
If match is found then I will put the values of d in two list.

qvec will store the valued of d from qm3
and dvec will store the value of d from m

The code I have so far.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Double> qe : qm3.entrySet()){
    for(Map.Entry<String, Double> de : m3.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(qe.getKey());
        if(qe.getKey().equals(de.getKey())){
            //System.out.println(qe.getKey());
            qvec.add(qe.getValue());
            dvec.add(de.getValue());
        }
        else {
            qvec.add(qe.getValue());
            dvec.add(0.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `Map`s have a [lookup function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) to get the value, if there is a mapping, that removes the need to iterate over the entire map?

Comment: Why aren't you using get?  this code is kinda impenetrable, what's a `qvec`?

Comment: Oh no, I am not familiar with these thing, how to use that or what is that lookup function ?

Comment: oh, Qvec and dvec is two list

Comment: No :( 
I want to match each key of qm3 ( d, e) to each key of m (e, c ,d ).
For example ,d will be compared with e, c, d.
If match is found then I will put the values of d in two list.
qvec will store the valued of d from qm3
and dvec will store the value of d from m

Comment: But `qm3` contains less keys than `m`, so the scenario that `m` doesn’t contain `qm3`’s key never applies.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class NewClass2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Double> qm3 = new HashMap<>();
        qm3.put("d", 0.2);
        qm3.put("e", 0.3);
        qm3.put("a", 0.8);
        Map<String, Double> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("e", 0.3);
        m.put("c", 0.4);
        m.put("d", 0.5);
        List<Double> qvec = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> dvec = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String key_from_qm3 : qm3.keySet()){    //for each key from qm3
            if(m.keySet().contains(key_from_qm3)){  //check if it exists in the keyset of m
                qvec.add(qm3.get(key_from_qm3));    //if yes put the value from qm3 into qvec. //map.get(key) returns the value for that key
                dvec.add(m.get(key_from_qm3));      // and the value from m into dvec
            }
        }

        System.out.println("qvec : " + qvec);
        System.out.println("dvec : " + dvec);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You should consider using `m.containsKey(key_from_qm3)` instead of `m.keySet().contains(key_from_qm3)`

Answer (score 0):

Your task, as far as understandable, can be achieved as follows:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Double> qe : qm3.entrySet()) {
    qvec.add(qe.getValue());
    dvec.add(m.getOrDefault(qe.getKey(), 0.0));
}
```

`qvec` will contain all values of `qm3`, similar to the result of `qvec.addAll(qm3.values());` and `dvec` will contain the values associated with the same key or `0.0` if there was no mapping, however, it must be emphasized that `HashMap`s have no defined order. So only filling both lists within the loop ensures that the resulting positions are associated with the same key. Still, it is completely undefined, which key is associated with which position.

Further, `qm3` contains less keys than `m` in your example, so the fallback of `0.0` will never apply.

---

Perhaps, you want to consider all keys of both maps:

```
LinkedHashSet<String> keys = new LinkedHashSet<>();
keys.addAll(qm3.keySet());
keys.addAll(m.keySet());
for(String key: keys) {
    qvec.add(qm3.getOrDefault(key, 0.0));
    dvec.add(m.getOrDefault(key, 0.0));
}
```

This creates a `LinkedHashSet` containing all keys, which will retain the order in which they were inserted, so you can also use that set later-on to find out, which list position is associated with which key. Then it will populate the lists, using the `0.0` default for both.